# Getting current route name / url using AngularDart5

Tags: angular, dart, angular-ui-router, angular-dart

I noticed an `OnActivate` in the Angular docs and i'm trying to implement it in order to change the UI based on the current route.

```
@Component(
    selector: "blah", 
    template: """blah""", 
    directives: const [routerDirectives])
class Blah extends Object with Reuse implements OnActivate {

    @override
    void onActivate(RouterState previous, RouterState current) {
        window.alert("Activated");
        print("activated");
    }

}
```

reloading the page or using the router to switch routes and the onActivate is not triggering

I'm using this snippet of code to navigate which does work:

```
  void navigate(RouteDefinition route) {
    final NavigationParams params =
        new NavigationParams(queryParameters: {"project-id": "1", "workspace-id": "2"}, replace: true);

    router.navigate(route.path, params);
  }
```

What am i missing here?

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: blah
version: 0.0.0
description: Blah

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.3.1
  angular_forms: ^2.1.2
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+22
  event_bus: any
  http: any
  js: ^0.6.0
  logging: ^0.11.3+1
  html: any
  html_unescape: ^1.0.1+2
  google_maps: ^3.4.1

  someothercomponent:
    path: ../someothercomponent

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: 2.3.0
  build_runner: ^1.5.2
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

**EDIT**: I don't know if this is related in any way, when i inject the router via a constructor,

```
  final Router router;

  ProjectLayout(this.router) {

    log.fine(this.router.current.toUrl());

  }
```

this.router.current is null

Adding `this.route`,

```
  final RouterState route;
  final Router router;


  ProjectLayout(this.router, this.route) {

    log.fine(route.toUrl());

  }
```

it complains `No provider found for RouterState`, adding RouterState as a provider, the error changes into something very bizarre:

```
dart_sdk.js:99585 EXCEPTION: No provider found for String: RouterState -> String.
**NOTE**: This path is not exhaustive, and nodes may be missing in between the "->" delimiters. There is ongoing work to improve this error message and include all the nodes where possible. 
STACKTRACE: 
dart:sdk_internal                                                          throw_
package:angular/src/di/injector/injector.dart 20:3                         throwsNotFound
package:angular/src/di/injector/injector.dart 92:14                        get
package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 313:28                       injectorGet
package:angular/src/di/injector/element.dart 23:16                         [_injectFrom]
package:angular/src/di/injector/element.dart 31:7
```

So it would be nice to get this working using OnActivate, just as nice would be to get it to work via router injection

Comment: yeah, the directives work fine, i've added `<a [routerLink]=...` and that works fine. The OnActivate is mentioned in the tutorial, it should probably work the same in the TypeScript version: https://angulardart.dev/guide/router/3

Answer (score 0):

So based on discussions on gitter, it seems `OnActivate` only works on components that are directly switched in / out of the router outlet, thus OnActivate will never work on child components.

Looking at `router`'s source code, i noticed this comment:

```
/// Note this isn't updated until after all `onActivate` implementations are
  /// invoked, and [onRouteActivated] fires.
  RouterState get current;
```

That means `router.current` only becomes non-null in components where OnActivate works and only after onActivate was triggered.